# Accessing Post method from View through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I am facing problems accessing the ActionResult [Post] from my View.

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
<form id="edit-order-form" action="@Href("~/Orders/Edit")">///EDIT:
   ....

  <div class="row">
            <span class="label"><label for="ShipPostalCode">PostalCode:</label></span>
            <input type="text" id="txtShipPostalCode" name="ShipPostalCode" value="@ViewBag.ShipPostalCode" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <span class="label">&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="submit" id="btnSave" name="submit" value="Save" />
        </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#btnSave").live("click", saveRecord);

function saveRecord() {

$.ajax(
 { type: "Post" ,
     url: '@Url.Action("Save", "OrdersList")',
     data: {
    OrderID: $("#hdnOrderID").val(),
    ShipName: $("#txtShipName").val(),
    ShipAddress: $("#ShipAddress").val(),
    RequiredDate: $("#RequiredDate").val(),
    ShipPostalCode: $("#ShipPostalCode").val(),
         },
         dataType: "html" ,
         success: function  (data){
             alert ('saved');
              }
     }).....
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Save(int orderId = 0, string ShipName = "", string ShipAddress = "", string ShipPostalCode = "", DateTime? RequiredDate = null)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetOrders", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "GetOrders", "connection string");

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", orderId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShipName", ShipName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShipAddress", ShipAddress);
            SqlParameter paramDate = cmd.Parameters.Add("@RequiredDate",
            System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
            paramDate.Value = RequiredDate;
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequiredDate", RequiredDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShipPostalCode", ShipPostalCode);

            //SqlParameter Total = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.Int);
            //Total.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();



            conn.Close();


            return View();
        }
    }
```

The controller action doesn't get called. Probably the javascript function neither.

Comment: Change your input type from `submit` to `button` and just add `onclick="saveRecord()"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `document.forms[0].submit();` instead? To see if it's a problem with the posting or your javascript?

Also .live is deprecated, you should be using .on instead.

example code:

```
$("#btnSave").on("click", saveRecord);

//or $("#btnSave").click( function(){
//    document.forms[0].submit();
//});

function saveRecord() {
    document.forms[0].submit();
 })
```

And change your Save action result's attributes to `[HttpPost]` and below that `[ActionName("Edit")]`

Comment: where (and how) exactly do I use this document.forms[0].submit();?

Comment: Edited my original comment for you. Also this assumes that this is the only form on the page (hence the zero based index).

Comment: function saveRecord() {
    document.forms[0].submit();
 })
and then the ajax function, right??

Comment: No, that replaces the ajax function.

Comment: Then how is the ActionResult (in my controller) gonna get called?? And how do I pass the parameters that I am passing in the ajax function??

Comment: Didn't see that. What you can do is put the following attributes above your save actionresult.
        [HttpPost()]
        [ActionName("Edit")]

Comment: And btw, "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function"

Comment: Edited my comment, I will add it in to my original post

Comment: My Save method already has the attribute [Http Post] (see code). Plus, I already have an Edit method in my controller. Also, how does changing the name of the method matter?

Comment: It allows you to override MVC conventions and specify that a certain action result is linked to another existing action result. In this case the save action result is linked to the edit action result as it's posting action.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing... but I'll have to admit my mistake. I gave the controller name wrong. It seems to be working fine now. Thanks for all your efforts (esp. the last comment).

Answer (score 0):

First what you need to do is change the 'type' attribute of the 'btnSave' input element to 'button' so it doesn't post the page when clicked. 'Input' elements with the type of 'submit' will actually post the page, which is not what you want when you want to execute javascript when a button is clicked.

Next what you'll need to do is use either IE or Chrome and pull up the Developer tools, 'F12'. In Chrome, click the 'Sources' tab, then open the 'Navigator' by clicking the 'boxed arrow' below the 'Elements' tab. Find the file which holds your javascript and breakpoint the line which has the following syntax, `$.ajax(`.  Then go to your page and click the 'Submit' button. From there, you should see exceptions that are most likely causing your javascript to fail.

Also, you may want to open 'Fiddler' and watch to see if the 'Post' to your RESTful service is kicking off.

Comment: after changing type to "button" I get a resource not found error (meaning Action result Save not found). The reason as per me is [Http Post] at the top of this method. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: For testing's sake, remove the '@URL.Action...' and just put the actual URL, and see if you get a successful response.